# Vundle plugin: Install concrete version of plugin

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I use vim and try the 'Vundle'. It helps to install plugins like in Ruby on Rails:

```
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'  
             ... I write in my _vimrc file
```

But when I do saw, it installs the last version of this plugins from github. But I want to install one of the previous version. Who knows how to do what I want?

Comment: I don't think you can specify a version with Vundle, as that is still an item on the todo list ("allow specify revision/version?"). Check out kana's [vim-flavor](https://www.relishapp.com/kana/vim-flavor) instead for a versioned approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think Vundle allows you to specify a repo ref. I think you can work around this though. Vundle assumes you want the master's head, so create your own fork to get control of the version.

In other words, fork the plugin repo, reset the master branch to the version you want, and use your fork in the `.vimrc`

```
Bundle '<your username>/nerdcommenter'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install a specific version through vundle. Somehow.

- First install your bundle as normal.
- Then, go to the bundle directory (e.g. `cd ~/.ssh/bundle/nerdtree`) and checkout the version you need: `git checkout <thecommithash-or-release>`.

Tada!

You can never ever update through vundle tho :)

Answer (score 0):

There's also a forgotten pull request to allow installing specific plugin versions: https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/pull/681 with syntax:

```
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim', {'version': '1.79'}
```

which confirms it is not possible nicely from inside Vimscript. Shame, that feature is a must have...

This is also mentioned on the [current README](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/tree/b255382d6242d7ea3877bf059d2934125e0c4d95) in the TODO list:

> allow specifying revision/version?